# Draw image on canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Why does nothing show up on the canvas? The picture is in the same folder as the code, I've tried to directly copy some code, and just change the sources, it still doesn't work. That leads me to believe, that it is not a fault in the actual way I draw the picture, but in the way I load the canvas?
I can add other stuff to the canvas, just not pictures.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.width = 800;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    var imag = new Image();

    imag.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    };
    imag.src = "underwater.png";

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is `imageObj`? You use it in your `drawImage` call, but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Did you check for errors ? Declared `ctx` and using `context` ...

Answer (score 0):

You most likely copied this code from somewhere and forgot to change the image object name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.width = 800;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    var imag = new Image();

    imag.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imag, 0, 0);
    };
    imag.src = "underwater.png";

</script>
</body>
```